# Getting an error when trying to install react using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-install, react-18

Getting an error when trying to install react using npx create-react-app.. Please help.
node version = v16.13.2
npm version = 8.6.0
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

next

`npx create-react-app my-app`

above commands worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide app name

```
npx create-react-app [app-name]
```

Comment: I used dot to install it in the current directory  (npx create-react-app .) I used this command (npx create-react-app [app-name]) but still getting the same error